# What is meant with an $X$ in the particle data booklet?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, notation, strong-force

What is meant with the $X$ in some decay channel of the $B^0$ ?

[B⁰ PDG Booklet](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2014/listings/rpp2014-list-B-zero.pdf)

I imagine it could be an unidentified resonance, but I cannot find a definition. What especially confuses me is that once it comes with a subscript $X_c$. Does this imply that it is a charmed resonance?

Comment: see also the X(   resonances in this table , page 113 http://pdg.lbl.gov/2015/html/Summary_Tables_FullBook_2014.pdf

Comment: I don't think its the X-resonance since it is listed without an energy in the brackets

Comment: It is generic, in the same sense that a D is listed in higher up similar decays

Comment: $X$ is used in two ways: one is the answer to this question, the other (as of the recent overhaul to the hadron naming scheme) is for exotic meson candidates with unknown quantum numbers.

Answer (score 3):

$B \rightarrow e^{+} + \nu_{e} + X_c$ is a semi-leptonic decay denoting a $b \rightarrow c$ flavor transition at the quark level. $X_c$ then simply denotes charm-final states i.e. the final decay products that the detectors sees as hadrons. Usually, in flavor physics, X denotes a final state hadron, and the subscript c helps identify the possible hadronization products from the charm quark. 
Therefore, if you see a semi-leptonic decay with $X_u$ as a final product, then that tells you it's a $b \rightarrow u$ flavor transition.

The [QCD section of the PDG](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2016/reviews/rpp2016-rev-qcd.pdf) states that "Free quarks have never been observed, which is understood as a result of a longdistance,
confining property of the strong QCD force: up, down, strange, charm, and
bottom quarks all hadronize, i.e. become part of a meson or baryon, on a timescale $∼ 1/Λ$ where $\Lambda$ is the scale where the perturbatively-defined QCD coupling diverges and non-perturbative dynamics dominates".